# In The Umbrella Academy TV series, why doesn't Number 5 have a name?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

While Number 5 did leave home at a younger age than his siblings, he was old enough that he should already have been given a name by Grace, his animatronic mother, like the other six Hargreeves children. Why does he seem to have never been given a normal name?

Answer (score 8):

None of the children were named by Professor Hargreeves or Grace -- they were only called by their numbers until they chose their own names.  The others chose names by early teens at the latest; Number 5 never bothered.

This is based on character dialog over several episodes from the TV series; I haven't read the comics.

Comment: Diego says in Episode 1, "My name is Number Two. You know why? Because our father couldn't be bothered to give us actual names. He had Mom do it."

That seems to rule out the kids choosing their own names.

Comment: @E.J. I think Zeiss Ikon is talking about the distinction between legal names and chosen ones. Diego's actual legal name is Number Two picked by Mom. Diego is his chosen nickname, that he picked himself.

Comment: I don't think that's the best interpretation of that quote--we see Vanya being called Number Seven by multiple nannies before Mom was ever created, implying that Sir Reginald is the one who assigned numbers to the children as legal names, not Mom. In any case, given the number of years between the children's birth and Mom's creation, Sir Reginald would have had to have called them *something* in the interim.